# Preprocessing a word before spell checking in Vim

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I use Vim's spell checking to validate texts in Russian. We have letter `ё` in our alphabet which is often replaced with simple `е`. So, for example, word `ёжик` из written as `ежик`. It is a bad tone actually. Its like using - (hyphen) where — (em-dash) is required, like using "computer" quotes forgetting about existence of „typographic” «quotes», etc.

The bad thing is that spell dictionary for Vim composed out of simplified words with all `ё`s, replaced with `е`s. So I always get an error in a word with `ё`.

So the question, is there any hook I can use that will allow me to normalize a word just before it will be spell checked? Or maybe someone has a better idea? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

With the hint from @sarnold, I found the solution. One should use ru_yo locale instead of ru_ru if he wants ёёёёё

Comment: Is not Russian second level typographic quotes `„“` instead of `„”`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought when reading your post was to suggest using `zg` to add the word to the spellfile; after a few weeks you'll have a lot of them. Not ideal, but simple.

`:help spell-russian` lists several different spelling variations, would one of these help?

I also notice in `:help spell.txt` that there are options for downloading your own spellfiles from OpenOffice or http://www.a-a-p.org to automate building spellfiles.

Comment: Oh yeah! All is simpler than I thought. Looking at `:help spell-russian` I discovered that there is `ru_yo` locale along with `ru_ru`. It is `ё`-friendly, this is *exactly* what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use your own spell checking for vim. Use a method #2 [explained here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/vim-editor-how-to-correct-spelling-mistakes-automatically/)

Comment: Can't understand how it could help me. Do you suggest to auto-correct good spelling to bad spelling? I'm trying to avoid this and preserve spell checking functionality at the same time.